# Trying to add array element to a maybe existing config file

Tags: jq

I'm testing the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

element="$(jo -p \
    locations=["$(jo \
        name="$name" \
        address="$address" \
        latitude=$lat \
        longitude=$long \
        gridId=$grid_id \
        gridX=$grid_X \
        gridY=$grid_Y \
        countyUGC="$countyUGC" \
        zoneUGC="$zoneUGC" \
        stationId="$stationId")"])"

if [[ -e weather.locations ]]; then
    jq --argjson element "$element" '. += $element' \
        weather.locations >weather.locations.temp && mv weather.locations.temp weather.locations
else
    echo "$entry" >weather.locations
fi
```

The 1st time I run this, the file will not exist (reason for my `[[ ]]`).  But subsequent times, it seems to always modify the initial element instead of adding.  My goal: Append location array with new element (I don't see any need for updating, but "name" would be the field to key off of)

output of the jo: (of course all the fields would be filled in)

```json
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "name": "home",
      "address": "123 Main St, MyTown MyState",
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "gridId": null,
      "gridX": null,
      "gridY": null,
      "countyUGC": null,
      "zoneUGC": null,
      "stationId": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jo` command produces an object with a "locations" field, whose value will be used to replace the one of the existing object (`.` refers to the outlying object rather than to its "locations" array).

Instead you'll want the following :

```
jq --argjson element "$element" '.locations += $element.locations'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I would have figured it out.  I originally went with `.` since the input already referenced the "locations" field

Comment: @rr0ss0rr the idea is that the input is an object rather than an array, and adding to it will not behave in the same way as adding to an array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .. that was the piece that was confusing me.